# Cannot Find Symbol: Variable >object> of type <Class>?

Tags: java, syntax, symbols

I'm working through some extra credit projects and when I try to submit it through the auto-check server for my program, it gives me a Symbol Not found error and stops running my code...I'm not entirely sure why because everything seems in scope and spelled correctly.

Any ideas?

```
public class Chap72 {    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //User inputs url and name of file to create.
        WebReader instance = new WebReader();

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a URL");
        String url = console.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter name of file");
        Scanner location = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fileName = location.next();
        String filename = "PARSEDRESULT.txt";

        try {
            //uses both saveURL for the unaltered HTML
            //uses SaveToURLPage for extracting links.
            instance.SaveToURLPage(url, filename);
            instance.saveURL(instance.Navigate(url), fileName);


        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            //catches MalformedURLException
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
instance.SaveToURLPage(url, filename);
        ^
symbol:   method SaveToURLPage(String,String)
location: variable instance of type Chap72
1 error
```

I'm not entirely sure why I'm getting this error...

```
WebReader

public class WebReader implements WebPage {

/**
 *
 * @param url to search through
 * @return pageLocation
 * @throws MalformedURLException
 */
public URL Navigate(String url) throws MalformedURLException {
    //Creates a URL object
    URL pageLocation = new URL(url);
    return pageLocation;
}

/**
 *
 * @param location url hypertext link
 * @param fileName name of text file to save to
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void saveURL(URL location, String fileName) throws IOException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(location.openStream());
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fileName);
    //Scans the website
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        //prints out Information from URL
        out.println(in.nextLine());

    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}

/**
 *
 * @param url to search through
 * @param filename to save to
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void SaveToURLPage(String url, String fileName) throws IOException {

    // Creates a new URL object to retreive information.
    URL pageLocation = new URL(url);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(pageLocation.openStream());
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fileName);

    while (in.hasNext()) {
        //Cycles through each character
        String line = in.next();
        if (line.contains("href=\"http://")) {
            //if it has an <a> tag, the link is extracted
            int from = line.indexOf("\"");
            int to = line.lastIndexOf("\"");
            out.println(line.substring(from + 1, to));
        }
    }
    in.close(); //closes program
    out.close();
}
```

}

Comment: The method does not exist?

Comment: It's suspicious that the error says "variable instance of type Chap72".  That implies that you have a variable named `instance` whose type is `Chap72`; in other words, it isn't the `instance` that you've shown us whose type is `WebReader`.  Do you have another `instance` somewhere else, that you try to call `SaveToURLPage` on?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The only instance I created was an object called instance for the WebReader class so I could use the SaveToURLPage method.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the issue is here; like @ajb mentioned, the type ought to be `WebReader` and not `Chap72`. Could you try using `this.instance` instead of simply `instance` and tell us what you get?

Comment: What is the "auto-check server" you mentioned?

Comment: Where would I inherit instance? It's telling me I can't since its non-static. Do you think I should Refactor the class names?

Comment: Its Virginia Tech's Web-CAT server

Comment: @Rimshot I don't know exactly what error you're getting about "inheriting instance", but Roney's suggestion about `this.instance` shouldn't have compiled since `instance` is a local variable in a method, not a field.  The whole thing seems awfully weird to me, which is why I was asking about the "auto-check server"--maybe there are errors in how it's operating, or maybe it's reading obsolete files.  If you have access to a Java compiler without this server, and you have access to all the classes you need, I'd try to recompile everything there from scratch.

Comment: I've come to the conclusion this is a server side issue. I've recompiled the code and debugged it to the greatest extent and it functions perfectly well on my end. However, when it trys to run tests on it using whatever algorithm its using, its failing my entire project. It doesn't even see it as running....

Comment: Well, if you can document what you've done and show it to the professor, hopefully you can demonstrate that it's a server issue and get your extra credit.  I wish you the best of luck.

Answer (score 3):

This error means that there is no such method `SaveToURLPage` that accepts two `String` objects as parameters declared in the `WebReader` class.  For any further assistance, you'll need to post the contents (or JavaDoc) of the `WebReader` class, for us to see.

Comment: Updated the OP with the WebReader class.